# how to multiple authentication with url in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use authentication for engine site and user profile.
when I entered with engine site and change url to page user , my authentication is not change.how to fix it?
web.config code is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

login form (user and engine) for authentication code is ?

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
string cookiestr;
HttpCookie ck;
tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, listBU[0].UserName, DateTime.Now, chRemmember.Checked ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) : DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), true, "user");
cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
if (true)
     ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration;
ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

and check for authentication code is:

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //do
}
```

how to create multiple authentication for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

authentication for engine site and user profile use role for that.